# Rendezvou course for moving boats

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

There is a boat travelling along a straight line on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ with its location at time t given by $ (t \cos(\theta_a), t \sin(\theta_a) ) $. I'm in a boat that starts at $(x_b, y_b)$ and travels a fixed speed of $v$.  My location at time $t$ is given by $ (vt \cos(\theta_b) + x_b, vt \sin(\theta_b) + y_b ) $.

I can pick my angle $ \theta_b$.  I wish to pick an angle so that I meet up with the other vessel. In other words given $x_b$, $y_b$, $v$ and $ \theta_a$ find $\theta_b$ such that a some time $t_r$ the following equality holds $(t_r \cos(\theta_a), t_r \sin(\theta_a)) = (t_rv \cos(\theta_b) + x_b, t_rv \sin(\theta_b) + y_b) $.

Now clearly there are some combinations of speed and location where there will be no solution.  However in the cases where there is a solution how do I solve it?

Comment: Choose $\theta_b$ such that the boats won't travel in parallel direction.  Now you can calculate uniquely the velocity $v$ -- which might be negative -- by equation the two positions.

Comment: My speed is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the unit-direction vectors of the lines $\vec a=(\cos\theta_a,\sin\theta_a)$ and $\vec b=(\cos\theta_b,\sin\theta_b)$, resp., and let $\vec p=(x_b,y_b)$ and $\phi$ the angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec p$. We're trying to solve $\vec at=vt\vec b+\vec p$, assume $v>0$.  From here $\vec a-v\vec b$ is parallel to $\vec p$ and must have length $v$.  This gives an easy way to construct $v\vec b$.

Draw $\vec a$, $\vec p$ and a circle  with center $(0,0)$ and radius $v$.  The parallel to $\vec p$ through $\vec a$ meets that circle in two points, provided that  $v>|\sin(\phi)|$.  These are the candidates for $v\vec b$.

A straightforward computation gives 
$$v\vec b=\vec a-\frac{\vec p}{\|\vec p\|}\left(\cos(\phi)\pm\sqrt{v^2-\sin^2(\phi)}\right).$$
From here it's easy to calculate the time and place where both vessels meet.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that may also be useful to understand why there can be two, one, or no solutions - depending on the combination of speed and location - is the following.  Let us call $A $ the point $(t \cos \theta_a, t \sin \theta_a) $ where the two boats meet, and $B $ the point $(x_b,y_b ) $ from which the second boat starts. Also note that, because the first boat reaches $A $ in the time $t $ moving along a line with angle $\theta_a $, it starts at the origin and has velocity equal to $1$.

Since the second boat must run the distance between $B $ and $A $ with velocity $v $ in the time $t $, we can write

$$\sqrt {(t \cos \theta_a-x_b)^2 + (t \sin \theta_a-y_b ) ^2}=vt$$

We can then solve the resulting second degree equation  for $t $, which is the only unknown quantity. This leads to

$$t^2 \cos^2 \theta_a  -  2x_b t \cos \theta_a  +x_b^2 + t^2 \sin^2 \theta_a  -  2y_b t \sin \theta_a  +y_b^2=v^2t^2$$

$$(v^2-1)t^2   + 2 t (x_b \cos \theta_a     +     y_b \sin \theta_a) -x_b^2  -y_b^2=0$$

$$t= \frac {1}{v^2-1} \left(-x_b \cos \theta_a - y_b \sin \theta_a \pm \sqrt {    ( x_b \cos \theta_a     +      y_b \sin \theta_a ) ^2  +(v^2-1)(x_b^2  +y_b^2)} \right)$$

This equation expresses $t $ as a function of the coordinates $(x_b,x_b) $, the velocity $v $ and the angle $ \theta_a $. If there are positive real solutions for $t $, we can get corresponding solutions for the angle $ \theta_b $ by considering that

$$ \theta_b=\arctan_2 \left( t \sin \theta_a-y_b, t \cos \theta_a -x_b\right) $$

where $\arctan_2(q, p)$ is the common variation of the $\arctan $ function, used to identify  the appropriate quadrant of the computed angle and defined as the angle  between the positive $x$-axis and the line connecting the point with coordinates $(p, q)$ with the origin.

Now let us study the number of valid solutions. First let us set, by simplicity,   $ x_b \cos \theta_a     +      y_b \sin \theta_a=J$. The equation giving $t $ can then be rewritten as

$$t= \frac {1}{v^2-1} \left(-J \pm \sqrt { J^2  +(v^2-1)(x_b^2  +y_b^2)} \right)$$

Since by definition $t $ must be positive, the number of valid solutions obtained for $t $ (and for $ \theta_b $) depends on whether the determinant

$$J^2  +(v^2-1)(x_b^2  +y_b^2)$$

is positive, zero, or negative, and on whether the  resulting  solutions  for $t $ are positive or negative. In particular,  the determinant is $\geq 0$ if

$$v^2 \geq 1- \frac {J^2}{x_b^2  +y_b^2}$$

or equivalently if

$$v^2 \geq \frac {(x_b \sin \theta_a   +    y_b \cos \theta_a)^2}{x_b^2  +y_b^2}$$

Considering that $v $ is by definition positive, we have

$$v \geq \frac {|x_b \sin \theta_a     +      y_b \cos \theta_a|}{\sqrt {x_b^2  +y_b^2}}$$

where it can be easily shown that the quantity in the RHS (let us call it $K $), for  $ x_b^2  +y_b^2 \neq 0$, is $\leq 1$. The value of $K $ can be interpreted as the minimal velocity that is necessary (albeit not sufficient as a condition) for a valid solution to exist.

As a  result, looking again at the formula above that provides the solutions for $t $, we have the following cases:

- CASE 1: $v>1$ (second boat faster than the first one). The determinant is positive and the absolute value of the radical is higher than $|J|$,  so that the  two values of $t $ are real, one positive and one negative. Thus, there is only one valid solution. This is also intuitive: whatever the angle $\theta_a $ and the initial position of the second boat, there is no way, for the first boat, to "escape" for an infinite time if the second boat is faster.
- CASE 2: $v=1$ (equal velocity between the first and second boat). In this case, the initial  second degree equation loses its $t^2$ term and reduces to a first degree equation whose solution is

$$ t =\frac {x_b^2  +y_b^2}{ 2 (  x_b \cos \theta_a     +      y_b \sin \theta_a) }= \frac {x_b^2  +y_b^2}{2J }   $$

which is valid only if $J >0$. A very simple example falling in this case is when $\theta_a=0$ (i.e., the first boat moves horizontally along the $x $-axis) and the initial position of the second boat is on the $y=x $ line, e.g. $x_b=y_b=z $. Here, if the boats have equal velocity, the trivial solution is given by a direct vertical movement of the second boat towards the point $(z,0) $, so that both boats perpendicularly converge to this point  with velocity $1$, covering a distance $z $ in the time $z $. Accordingly, the formula above reduces to $ t =(2z^2)/( 2 z )= z$.

- CASE 3: $k <v <1$ (second boat slower than the first one, but with velocity higher than the "minimal" velocity $k $). The determinant is still positive and the absolute value of the radical is lower than $| J |$,  so that the  two values of $t $ have concordant sign. Thus, there are two valid solutions if $J$ is positive and no valid solutions if $J$ is negative. A simple scenario for the case in which two valid solutions are obtained is the  trivial case where $ \theta_a=0$ and the first boat runs horizontally rightward along the positive $x $-axis (so that its arrival point $A $ has coordinates $(t,0) $ ), and where $x_b>0$ and  $y_b=0$ (i.e. the starting point of the second boat lies on the positive  $x $-axis as well). In this case, the equation providing the solutions for $t $ has a positive determinant and reduces to
  $$t= \frac {1}{v^2-1} (-x_b \pm x_b v)$$

giving the two solutions

$$t= \frac {x_b}{v+1}$$
$$t= -\frac {x_b}{v-1} $$

The first solution, which can also be written as $vt=x_b-t $,  refers to that in which $t <x_b $, i.e.  the second boat runs towards the left along the $x $-axis towards the first boat with velocity $v $, covering the distance  between its starting point and the point $(t,0) $ in the time $t $.  The second solution, which can be written as $vt=t-x_b $, refers to the case in which $t>x_b$,  so that the second boat runs towards the right along the $x $-axis just as the first boat, but with a lower velocity (so that it is reached by the first boat at the point $(0,t) $ in the time $t $). Also note that this second case is clearly valid only for $v <1$. Specular solutions exists in the case that the two boats move along the negative $x $-axis.

- CASE 4: $v=k $ (second boat slower than the first one, with velocity equal to the minimal velocity $k $). The determinant is zero, so that there is one valid solution  if $J$ is positive and no valid solution if $J$ is negative.
- CASE 5: $0 <v <k$. The determinant is negative and there are no real solutions for $t $.

In summary:

- there is always one valid solution for $t $ and $\theta_b$ when $v>1$, that is to say if the velocity of the second boat is higher than that of the first boat;
- there is no valid solution when $v<K$, that is to say if the velocity of the second boat is lower than a value representing the "minimal" velocity;
- for intermediate values of $v $ ranging from $K $ to $1$, there can be two, one or no valid solutions, and this can be established by looking at $J $, a quantity easily calculated from $\theta_a $, $x_b $, and $y_b $.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  |\mathbf{v}_{a}-\mathbf{v}_{b}| &= v \\
  \mathbf{v}_{a}^2-2\mathbf{v}_a \cdot \mathbf{v}_b+\mathbf{v}_b^2 &= v^2 \\
  1-2\cos (\theta_a-\theta_b)v_b+v_b^2 &= v^2 \\
  \cos (\theta_a-\theta_b) &= \frac{1+v_b^2-v^2}{2v_b}
\end{align*}

By triangular inequality,
$$|\mathbf{v}_{a}-\mathbf{v}_{b}|=v \implies
|v_a-v| \le v_{b} \le v_a+v$$

$$|1-v| \le v_{b} \le 1+v$$

For real $v_b$,

\begin{align*}
  4\cos^2 (\theta_a-\theta_b)-4(1-v^2) & \ge 0 \\
  4[v^2-\sin^2 (\theta_a-\theta_b)] & \ge 0 \\
  \sin^2 (\theta_a-\theta_b) & \le v^2
\end{align*}

Comment: What does $\mathbf{v}_a$ represent in this solution?

Comment: $$\mathbf{v}_a=\dfrac{d\mathbf{r}_a}{dt}=\dfrac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} t\cos \theta_a \\ t\sin \theta_a \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta_a \\ \sin \theta_a \end{pmatrix}$$  Mind your denotation, your position should read \begin{pmatrix} v_b t \cos \theta_b + x_b \\ v_bt \sin \theta_b + y_b \end{pmatrix}  and the relative speed should be $$v=|\mathbf{v}_{a}-\mathbf{v}_{b}|$$

Comment: This seems to suggest that your starting location doesn't matter to which course you should take.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I made an edit to clarify what I want.

Comment: You should think carefully and write clearly for what you ask. That's save our time. One downvote for this reason.  Last but not least, you should show your own effort and trial instead of being spoon fed.